# Example that shows if restriction of function is continuous at point c then function need not be continuous at point c

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

I practicing some exercises in real analysis. I came to following question.

**Question** Iet $A\subseteq B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and let $f:B→\mathbb{R}$ and $g$ be restriction of $f$ to $A$ then, show that by example, if $g$ is continuous at $c$ then it need not follows that $f$ is continuous at $c$

**My attempt**:  since $g$ is continuous at $c$ so that,  $\lim_{x \to c} g(x)= g(c)=f(c)$ but this need not be equal to $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ and hence $f$ need not be continuous at point $c$ .

**But Question asked for example**.
I saw hint that, take $f(x)=sgn(x)$ on $B=[0,1]$ and $g(x)=sgn(x)$ on $A=(0,1]$ and $c=0$.

**But i didn't understand this example!**

Because, as point $c=0$ is not in domain of $g(x)$ and hence how can be $g$ is continuous at point $c$?

(Since what i know, for contnuity of any function $f$ at a point $c$ we must have $f$ is defined at point $c$, $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ must exist and these two values i.e $f(c)$ and $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ must be equal)

So above example in hint is wrong? Am i correct? Is there is any other example?
Please help.

Comment: @Milten  no since $0$ is not in domain of $g$ so how can you define $g$ at that point?

Comment: The characteristic function of the rationals is discontinuous everywhere, but its restriction to the rationals (as well as its restriction to the irrationals) is everywhere continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the hint is wrong by the reason that you have mentioned: $0$ does not belong to the domain of $g$.

Instead, take $A=[0,\infty)$, $B=\Bbb R$, $c=0$,$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x\geqslant0\\0&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$and, of course, $g=f|_A$.

Comment: I think sir point $c$ here in your example is $0$? Or it is $1$? Sir please, can you add some more explanation about 'your example'

Comment: Yes, $c=0$ (and there was a typo in my answer). What more do you need to know? I suppose that it is clear that $g$ is continuous *everywhere*, since it is a constant function.

Comment: Now, its clear sir. Due to that typo, i am unable to get it. Thank you so much....

Comment: but here range of $f$ and $g$ are different but they should be same when we restrict functions right? or is it true always that if domain is restricted then range also gets restricted?

Comment: @AnkitaGoyal If we restrict the domain of a function then usually the range also gets restricted.